# Can I edit a variable in memory used by a python shell, in another python shell?

Tags: python, memory, shared-memory

Let's say I open 2 terminals, terminal1 and terminal2.

In terminal1 I type:

```
>>> myvariable = "yes"
```

In terminal2 I type:

```
>>> function_to_edit_memory(myvariable, "no")
```

And the change is reflected in terminal1?
Is this possible at all in Python?

Comment: No, not without explicit inter-process communication.

Comment: That's what I suspected. I could poll in terminal1 for changes to a shared file but that would be incredibly slow I think. How could this be done in memory?/faster?

Comment: google message passing interface

Comment: Like Martijn Pieters commented, this is not possible without some sort of inter-process communication. Without knowing what you are trying to achieve, perhaps some sort of TCP communication could be an alternative?